# send an event to a function by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to catch the event of `onmousemove` and send it to the function `mouseMoveOnCanvas`.

in the function of `mouseMoveOnCanvas` I am trying to get: `ev.currentTarget.offsetLeft`.

I tried to do the next thing:

```
document.getElementById('canvas_1234').onmousemove = (function (ev) {
    if (ev != null) {
        canvas_id = 'canvas_1234';
        return function () {

            mouseMoveOnCanvas(ev);
            //MouseOverColor(currentTd);
        }
    }
})();
```

but `ev` is always null.

I know I can do it with jquery:

```
$('canvas[id^="canvas_"]').live('mousemove', function (ev) {..}
```

but I want to do it with javascript.

any help appreciated!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use closure that way. Remove it and it should work.

```
document.getElementById('canvas_1234').onmousemove = function (ev) {
    if (ev != null) {
        canvas_id = 'canvas_1234';
        return function () {

            mouseMoveOnCanvas(ev);
            //MouseOverColor(currentTd);
        }
    }
};
```

What is happening is that the closure is calling the function by itself(on load) and not by the event. Further, you didn't pass anything on the parameter anyway - like this:

```
(function(ev) { console.log(ev); })("Hi");
```

Other point is that there's no reason why to return that anonymous as you're not returning nothing from it. Why not this ?

```
return mouseMoveOnCanvas(ev);
```

Comment: This is still not correct. The `event` should also be defined as argument to the anonymous function that is returned by the expression.

Comment: `ev` is not accesible within that anonymous? I though it is.

Comment: Now it is because you updated your code after my comment. You're welcome!

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I didn't updated because of your comment. I still believe that `ev` is  acessible inside that function. I need to check it out to be sure.

Comment: In the OP's example code, an *expression* is assigned to `onmousemove`. That expression returns an anon func `function() {}`. In that case, this anon func IS the event handler and thus it receives the `event` parameter. In the OP's code, the `event` param is not accessible outside the anon function. In the first version of your answer, you had it the same way that's why I commented.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp nice dude. Thank you for the tip. I'll check it out to understand better what you saiyng.